# Why am I unable to turn off recursion in ISC BIND?

Tags: bind

Here's my `named.conf.options` file:

```
options {
        directory "/var/cache/bind";
        dnssec-enable yes;

        auth-nxdomain no;    # conform to RFC1035
        listen-on-v6 { any; };

        # disable recursion
        recursion no;
};
```

I've tried adding `allow-recursion { "none"; }` before `recursion` but this also has no effect; I'm testing it by using `nslookup` on Windows, and using `google.com.` as the query (and it returns an IP, so I assume recursion is on). This issue occurs on two servers with similar setups.

Answer (score 1):

Just a quick one to rule out the obvious, do you have an:

```
include "/etc/bind/named.conf.options";
```

(or similar) somewhere in your /etc/bind/named.conf ?

Comment: Yep, included from `named.conf`.

Answer (score 0):

If the domain is already in the cache, there is no need for bind to do recursion, which might be why it returns a result even though you have recursion off.

Restart bind (to flush the cache), then try a few queries to domains.

You might also have issues if you're using views and the IP you're querying from is in a different view.